# Error when deploying SSIS project to Azure Data Factory using Self Hosted Integration Runtime

Tags: azure, ssis, azure-data-factory

I am trying to deploy my otherwise locally working SSIS project to the Azure Data Factory, but I seem to be getting many errors related to the Self Hosted Integration Runtime not being able to access the proper Connectors.

I am trying to load on-premise data to an Azure SQL Server, but I have ran into various errors, all related to the fact that the connection could not be established. I tried using ODBC, OLEDB and ADO.NET sources, but none of them worked, as all have failed to aquire the connection.

When I went into the log of the Self Hosted Integration Runtime, I can see that there are many warnings like the one below:

> Detect custom plugins from , but failed with exception 'Type=System.UnauthorizedAccessException,Message=Access denied for the following path: „C:\Program Files\Microsoft Integration Runtime\4.0\Shared\extconnectorslocal”.,Source=mscorlib,StackTrace=   a
>
> DEBUG:
> TraceComponentId: TransferClientLibrary
> TraceMessageId: CustomPluginLocalDetectionError

There are many more warning like this. Running the project locally, everyhing is fine, but when I deploy it to the SSISDB and try running it through the Integration Runtime, the project fails.

Thank you in advance for anyone helping out, I have been stuck on trying to configure the data load for many days.

Comment: Can you please provide some step by step screen shot that what you already did?
It will help to understand actual problem.

Comment: are you releasing as admin?